# Taking Desired Data From Xml

Tags: xml, linq

I have a sample XML Data as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employees>
 <Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Name>Shawn</Name>   
 </Employee>
 <Employee>
    <EmpId>2</EmpId>
    <Name>Neil</Name>
 </Employee>
 <Employee>
    <EmpId>3</EmpId>
    <Name>Kate</Name>
  </Employee>
 <Employee>
    <EmpId>4</EmpId>
    <Name>Robert</Name>
</Employee>
</Employees>
```

How to select second and third employee data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Skip()` and `Take()` extensions.

Example

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourdata.xml");
var list = doc.Elements("Employee").Skip(1).Take(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Enumerable.Take` and `Enumerable.Skip`:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlString);
IEnumerable<XElement> results = document.Root.Elements().Skip(1).Take(2);
```